# I am using Rails serialize to store Array of data, but my form is not saving array of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

a. I create a migration

```
def change
  add_column :tournament_matches, :team_a_sets, :text
  add_column :tournament_matches, :team_b_sets, :text
 end
```

b. I added Serialize in model

```
class TournamentMatch < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :team_a_sets, Array
  serialize :team_b_sets, Array
end
```

c. I allow strong params in my controller

```
  def tennis_params
    params.require(:tournament_match).permit(:match_result, team_a_sets: [], team_b_sets: []) 
  end
```

d. my form looks like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @tournament_match, url: update_tennis_game_result_tournament_match_path(@tournament_match), method: :patch do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :team_a, 'Team A' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_a_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_a_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_a_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_a_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_a_sets[]' %><br>

  <%= f.label :team_a, 'Team B' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_b_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_b_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_b_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_b_sets[]' %>
  <%= f.number_field 'team_b_sets[]' %><br>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

e. my controller looks like this

```
 def update_tennis_game_result
    tournament_match = TournamentMatch.find(params[:id])
    tournament_match.update_attributes(tennis_params)
    redirect_to tournament_path(tournament_match.tournament.id)
  end
```

But when I am submitting my form, I am getting empty array for `team_a_sets[]` and `team_b_sets[]`. What I am doing wrong ? I want to store games results in `team_a_sets` and `team_b_sets` as array.

My params after submitting my form looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Rd/3zOIv0Ldmq/qxlIDPcYzcAuhPmz20JYUpHedeeQSwtp4gf8RhYfXcLdhrlVdDQxGjHtCK6Cq0FB6FNWtdPQ==", "tournament_match"=>{"match_result"=>"home_win", "team_a_sets"=>[], "team_b_sets"=>[]}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"296b8505-c116-4e08-a48a-53366eac93b0"}
```

Comment: Do not use `serialize`. It has no place outside of legacy applications and your data will be completely unqueryable. You're building yourself into a dead end. Create a seperate join table instead. I can understand the "but assocations are hard and I just want have an array of stuff!" impulse but you're really just shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: I would also not use "serialize", but if you are using any decent modern database (mysql > 6 or so, pg > 9.4) you can use :json (:jsonb for pg) type instead of :text, which automatically converts from/to json while saving.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `form_helper` check the suffix `[]` to detect multiple fields.
But your form input

`<%= f.number_field 'team_a_sets[]' %>`

will generate html_tag like this

`input type="number" name="tournament_match[team_a_sets[]]" id="tournament_match_team_a_sets[]"`

in which the name hasn't the suffix `[]`.

you could try this instead:

`<%= form.number_field 'team_a_sets', multiple: true %>`

the html_tag is generated in this case

`input multiple="multiple" type="number" name="tournament_match[team_a_sets][]" id="tournament_match_team_a_sets"`

in which the html_name has suffix `[]`.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.